# Laravel Blade rendering <head> contents inside <body>

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I need a little help here...

When I try to render a simple template in blade, I get a bad rendered html.

I have `master.blade.php` and `home.blade.php` inside `views.admin` directory.

```
<!-- master.blade.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Test Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  Content
</body>
</html>

<!-- home.blade.php -->
@extends('admin.master')
```

The rendered HTML when I call `return view("admin.home");` looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test Title</title>
Content
</body></html>
```

Any ideas of what is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the case for the "`&#65279;`" character appearing is that it has been introduced by using a non UTF-8 encoded text editor or was introduced in a different way. My suggestion would be to use something like [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) or [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to create fresh versions of each of these three documents. This usually happens because of a copy/paste without realizing it or using a text editor that has "extra formatting" that you cannot see (e.g. Word). The character is ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE (you can see more information [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm)). So, it's not a Laravel Blade issue, it's that extra whitespace-type characters are being introduced by whichever text editor you're using.

Comment: I'm using Notepad++... I must said this is really strange but true... Controller by default is ANSI coded if I convert it to UTF-8 It stops working, no matter if I rewrite the whole thing again. Then if I convert my views to ANSI the html output gets right. So everything must be ANSI?

Comment: What happens if you just return view('admin.master') ?

Comment: If master.blade.php is ANSI coded it renders well, if UTF-8 it renders the same error as in the question. I just can't see why the change of character encoding messes up the output. There are no spaces, no special chars, no line breaks.

Comment: Thanks John I solve the issue encoding as UTF-8 without BOM. It renders well and I have UTF-8 encoding. You were right from the beginning, BOM equals ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE.

Answer (score 5):

For me, this was caused by adding a ; to end of @extends('layouts.app')

Answer (score 1):

I just spent about an hour trying to solve this, before deciding to make a new laravel app to paste new files over until it was fixed. It turns out my issue was because of a random character inserted into one of my config files (probably when trying to type in a url before realising my browser wasn't the active window). So if anyone can't seem to figure out why it isn't working after fixing their blade templates, check this.

Answer (score 0):

I know the thread is old, but I faced this issue today and removing BOM helped me to fix it. One hint - if you are using PHPStorm, there is option to remove BOM, without need to copy the file and save it with another file editor. Just right click on the file and press "Remove BOM". Works like charm!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for the sake of someone as me that had the same problem and came up to this page, I want to share what solved my problem.

As you may find in [laravel's layout documents](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates), it is stated that a master template **should be used like this**:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
 
@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')
    @@parent
 
    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@stop
 
@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@stop
```

My problem solved by adding `@stop` at the end of `@section('content')`. I hope this helps.